# Developer Friendly ERP

Tags: c#, erp

My company is currently using Sage MAS as their ERP system. While integrating our shopping cart is not going to be impossible, it uses COM and has it's own challenges.

I was wondering if there was a more developer friendly ERP out there. I have looked into Microsoft Dynamics but getting information on ERP systems that isn't a bunch of business jargon is next to impossible.

I will be using C# 3.whatever and .NET MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS Dyanamics is very cool app. V3 was fully Web Serviced V4 i assume even more- all actions are exposed as webservices, there is a big license hit on MS CRM due to "internet" licensing.

We use CRMv3 in a totally .NET SOA here and its great.

You should have no problems doing the integration - security aside =>

Answer (score 6):

When you talk about Microsoft Dynamics, it sounds a bit like you are talking about a specific product. However there are close to 10 different systems in the Dynamics line-up from Microsoft and at least 6 of them are different ERP system, all with different functionalities and extendabilities. The new verions of Microsoft Dynamics AX as well as Microsoft Dynamics NAV, have Web service support out of the box.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a bit of integration between ASP.NET and Dynamics AX4 - it has a .NET API called Business Connector that gives you access to AX's full internal object model - if AX does it, your web app can do it too. My app had to execute arbitrary AX business logic functions and, apart from the crummy API documentation (I've been spoiled by MSDN), it was all pretty easy. The Business Connector is the lowest-level API - there's a bunch of web service options as well that work at a higher level.